# Determine if process was pre-empted/blocked

Tags: c, linux

Between two points of code, is there anyway I can tell if the process has been pre-empted by the kernel, or rather has any other code been run on the same processor in that time?

```
//Point A
some_type capture = some_capture();
.
.
.
//Point B
if( interrupted( capture ) )
```

Is there any syscall that I can, or preferrably user-space variable I can read, which could implement the `some_capture` and `interrupted`?

I'm trying to improve some of my benchmarking code and would like to exclude such samples. Often I can use FIFO threads, but in some cases I cannot. Generally the things I am timing take way less than a time-slice and tend not to block, thus any measurement of when they do isn't an accurate measurement of the isolated function time.

Comment: No reply to your technical question (thus a comment): doing such micro-measurements is usually only possible with a certain probability of failure, Heisenberg strucks. Why do you need the time of individual runs and not an average over 100 or 1000 runs? This should be suitable if this is really such a short task that you investigate. If you measure these individually and there is a problem that some points of measurements being interrupted you should clearly see two different "populations".

Comment: The problem comes because I am doing many runs. One run is too short, I agree. But when I run 1000 of them the chance that the kernel interrupts increases. These interruptions greatly skew the numbers, even in large run lots.

Comment: You have to measure the individual runs with something that is not too intrusive (tick count or so) and by that classify them into those that did catch an interrupt and those that did not.

Comment: Now I kind of ignore results which are not likely. This is hard to do automatically -- the variation is high, but not often high enough to notice easily through stats. I was just hoping I could add an extra tool to my ability to detect bad tests.

Comment: As to the tick count, this is how I do timings, but for many of the things I time the overhead of the timer is still too big to not have large run sizes (it is a real pain to try and measure any thing sub-microsecond).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, but instead, you can call `sched_setscheduler()` to give your process `SCHED_FIFO` scheduling policy and a suitable (nonzero) priority.  That makes it a real-time task which cannot be interrupted except by another higher-priority real-time task (of which there are probably none).

Comment: …just noticed that you mentioned FIFO threads, so you probably already know about this.  And even `SCHED_FIFO` won't prevent things like interrupt handlers from running.

Comment: I do use FIFO in many cases, but sometimes I have tests where it isn't possible, or not preferable, for various reasons.

Comment: So we fall back to my initial statement of "I don't think you can do that".  :-)  Not from userspace, at least.  There might be kernel-level tracing tools that can tell you this, or some way to disable scheduling *and* interrupts on that processor.  But I don't have any knowledge in that area.